# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument while using pytest fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, fixtures

I have written my test classes in a file and I am trying to use [pytest fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html) so that I don't have to create the same input data in each test functions. Below is the minimal working example.

```
import unittest
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def base_value():
    return 5

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_add_two(self, base_value):
        result = base_value + 2
        self.assertEqual(result, 7, "Result doesn't match")
```

However, when I test this using pytest-3, I get the following error:

> TypeError: test_add_two() missing 1 required positional argument:
> 'base_value'

This is confusing for me since the base_value is clearly given as one of the arguments to `test_add_two`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is because you are mixing `pytest` and `unittest`. Try

```
@pytest.fixture
def base_value():
    return 5


class Test:
    def test_add_two(self, base_value):
        result = base_value + 2
        assert result == 7, "Result doesn't match"
```

And in case of failure the error will be

```
def test_add_two(self, base_value):
        result = base_value + 2
>       assert result == 8, "Result doesn't match"
E       AssertionError: Result doesn't match
E       assert 7 == 8
```

*But isn't pytest compatible with unittest?*

Only on a limited basis. From [Pytest unittest.TestCase Support](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses)

> pytest features in unittest.TestCase subclasses The following pytest
> features work in unittest.TestCase subclasses:
>
> - Marks: skip, skipif, xfail;
> - Auto-use fixtures;
>
> The following pytest features do not work, and probably never will due
> to different design philosophies:
>
> - **Fixtures (except for autouse fixtures, see below);**
> - Parametrization;
> - Custom hooks;
>
> Third party plugins may or may not work well, depending on the plugin
> and the test suite.

Comment: But isn't pytest compatible with unittest? I just want to keep both testing options open.

Comment: @Peaceful only on a limited basis, and not with fixtures (see updated answer).

Comment: Thanks! But the suggested modification throws an error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Test' and 'int'"

Comment: @Peaceful Did you change anything? what's your pytest version? this works fine for me...

Comment: My pytest version is 4.6.9. Also, I think self should be removed from your code, isn't it?

Comment: OK am not sure what I changed, but if I just copy paste your code and run in another file, it throws a large number of errors called  `<INTERNALERROR> ` and the last one is `<INTERNALERROR> IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @Peaceful Your Pytest version is quite old (01/20), try to update it.

Comment: In my case, I am not mixing anything. Found no trace of unittest...